# Writer dont writing in file but only create it

Tags: java, file, file-io

Im working on converter. I load file, start reading date from it and creating directories by year, month and day(+ another one dir) in witch ends are those converted text files. Everything is fine while creating those directories but in text files is nothing or only chunk of it.

```
public static void convertFile(File fileToConvert, File whereToSave, long shift) {
    BufferedReader reader = null;
    BufferedWriter writer = null;
    String oldDate = "";
    String newDate = "";
    boolean boolDate = true;

    try {

        for (File file : fileToConvert.listFiles()) {
            reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(file));

            boolean block = true;
            String line = "";
            int lineCounter = 0;
            while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                if (lineCounter==0) {
                    block = true;
                } else {
                    block = false;
                }

                line = line.replaceAll("[^0-9-,:+NaN.]", "");
                String[] data = line.split(",");

                if (block) {
                    data[0] = data[0].substring(0, 10) + " " + data[0].substring(10);
                    data[0] = SimulatorForRealData.timeShift(data[0], shift);
                    // ====================================================================================
                    newDate = data[0].substring(0, 4) + " " + data[0].substring(5, 7) + " "
                            + data[0].substring(8, 10);

                    String savingIn = SimulatorForRealData.createDirs(whereToSave.toString(),
                            data[0].substring(0, 4), data[0].substring(5, 7), data[0].substring(8, 10));

                    File f = new File(savingIn + "\\" + FILE_NAME + ".log");

                    if (!newDate.equals(oldDate) && boolDate == false) {
                        writer.close();
                        boolDate = true;

                    } else {
                        oldDate = newDate;
                        boolDate = false;

                    }

                    writer = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(f));



                    // =====================================================================================
                    writer.write("<in date=\"" + data[0].substring(0, 10) + "T" + data[0].substring(11)
                            + "\" t=\"1\" >\n");
                    writer.write(data[0] + "\n");
                    writer.write(0 + " " + 0 + " " + 0 + "\n");
                    for (int x = 0; x <= 10; x++) {
                        writer.write("NaN" + " ");
                    }
                    writer.write("\n");

                    for (String s : data) {
                        if (s.equals(data[0])) {
                            continue;
                        }
                        writer.write(s + ";");
                    }
                    writer.write("\n");
                } else {
                    for (String s : data) {
                        writer.write(s + ";");
                    }
                    writer.write("\n");
                }
                lineCounter++;
                if (lineCounter == 118) {
                    lineCounter = 0;
                    writer.write("</in>\n\n");
                }

            }
        }
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
        try {
            writer.close();
            reader.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Here is method where i perform it. Can someone help me. I tried different "writers" and nothing. I have suspicious that it will be problem in closing file but i dont know for sure.

Comment: After Java 7, you should always use try with resources to deal with io

Comment: maybe for my BufferedReader but i cant put there my BufferedWriter because i need put in it new paths for files

Comment: @Jacob, No it shouldn't but it is a better way, also of do you want to use try with resource the class should implements either `AutoClosable`, `Closable` interfaces

Comment: @JojoFranek, have you had a chance to debug your code ?
because it has another problem that it can throw a nullPointerException at 

`if (!newDate.equals(oldDate) && boolDate == false)  writer.close();`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I see two main problems:

1. You create a file every time you read a line. You should put it outside the loop (or loops, if you want only one file)
2. Always data is written with the same filename. It should have different filenames if you make a file for every file read.

Comment: thank you. I wrap calling constructor of BufferedWriter to if statement:
    if ((lineCounter == 0 && blockCounter == 48) || firstTime) {
      firstTime = false;
      blockCounter = 0;
      writer = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(f));
     }

Answer (score 1):

I think you should close every writer you created, not only last one.

```
for (File file : fileToConvert.listFiles()) {
   reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(file));
   ...
   writer = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(f));
   while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
       ....
   }
   writer.close();
}
```

writer flushes all changes on disk only when buffer is overflowed or it is closed.